# How to switch developer mode to production mode in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, production-mode

When I run:`sudo php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production`

Then i received

> Command returned non-zero exit code: /usr/bin/php7.0 -f
>   /var/www/html/magento/bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: @Rakesh Jesadiya, I think the question is not duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue

Run these commands:

```
1. sudo php bin/magento maintenance:disable
2. clear cache
3. sudo chmod 777 var* -R
4. sudo chmod 777 pub* -R
```

Comment: in my case, it was giving this error due to memory, so I run following command php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento deploy:mode:set production